# How to deploy a Vue.js app with env vars on Google Cloud Build?

Tags: firebase, docker, vue.js, google-cloud-build

I want to deploy a Vue.js app with google cloud build (to Firebase Hosting). Even if this is a fairly trivial use of the two products, the implementations of the two service for environment variables seems contradictory.

Google Cloud Build requires environment variables to start with "VUE_APP" prefix otherwise it completely ignores them and their content is undefined. On the other hand, Google cloud build requires variables to have the prefix "_", otherwise it throws the substitution variable is not "a valid built-in substitution". So I don't see anyway to pass the variables from the Google Cloud Build to the Vue.js app.

I also tried the following:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'ci', '--prefix', 'web/vue_js_landing/' ]
  env: [ 'VUE_APP_FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY=${_FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY}' ]
```

But it throws 'key in the template "VUE_APP_FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY" is not a valid built-in substitution'

Anyone aware of a workaround for this situation?

**Correction:**

This question was misleading. The code above answers my question. There's also a typo in it. It should have been "args: [ 'build', '--prefix', 'web/vue_js_landing/' ]". The error I mentioned, if someone else stumbles upon, this was triggered because I did "echo $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY" at some other point in my config and that's maybe because the ALLOW_LOOSE flag was not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your entire build config?  Please post if you have more

I'm not sure how the `VUE_APP` prefix is required in your context, but you can set substitutions and env vars without this prefix regularly.

Substitutions need `_` prefix are replaced during build but are not in env during build step. Env vars don't need extra prefix, but need to be called with `$$`.

How are you passing the web API Key?  Here is an example passing it through cli
`gcloud builds submit --no-source --substitutions _SECRET_KEY='123'`

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'echo $$FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY']
  env: ['FIREBASE_WEB_API_KEY=${_SECRET_KEY}']
```

Here is another example showing both substitutions and env variables.  You can run with `gcloud builds submit --no-source` if you want to play with it.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- id: 'breakout syntax'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
   - '-c'
   - |
     echo 'print all env vars'
     env
     echo 'print one env var with $$'
     echo '1: '$$BUILD_ENV_VAR
     echo '2: '$$STEP_ENV_VAR
     echo '3: '$$SUB_IN_ENV_VAR
     echo 'print one substitution with $ or ${}'
     echo '1: '${_SUB_VAR}
     echo '2: ' $$_SUB_VAR ## doesn't exist in env, fails
     echo '3: '$_SUB_VAR
  env: ['STEP_ENV_VAR=step-var']

substitutions:
    _SUB_VAR: sub-var
options:
    env:
     - BUILD_ENV_VAR=env-var
     - SUB_IN_ENV_VAR=env-var-with-${_SUB_VAR}
```

sources: [cloud build docs: subs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values), [cloud build docs: build steps](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#build_steps), [mastering cloud build syntax (bash things)](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf)

Comment: This answer is a piece of gold. I read all this references mentioned but couldn't put the pieces together. For what it's worth in Vue.js there is this restriction that only env vars starting with VUE_APP are available for security reasons. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html